# Strange files in every directory named "." and ".." in osx 10.9.2

Tags: macos

Anywhere I `ls -a` folder contains files called "." and "..".

Anybody knows what is this stuff? Is this some system files? Is this some kind of a virus or something? I have hard time googling because of such file names.

Here is an example:

`drwx------+ 12 mih  staff      408  4 янв 16:49 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 91 mih  staff     3094 20 мар 15:28 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 mih  staff     6148  4 янв 16:49 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 mih  staff        0 10 ноя  2011 .localized
-rw-r--r--@  1 mih  staff      181 27 ноя  2011 Desktop.ini
-rw-r--r--@  1 mih  staff  8198298 29 июл  2013 Dizzee Rascal - Bassline Junkie.mp3`

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes I am. That something basic?

Comment: How do you think `./runThing.sh` and `cd ..` work??

Comment: @BoristheSpider I dont know. I never used such stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are system files.

A subdirectiry contains two directory entries that were used to navigate between folders in the early days of DOS.

The `.` entry is a directory reference to the same directory.

The `..` entry is a directory reference to the parent directory.

Those are like regular subdirectories, but instead they point to directories that already exist.

Nowadays those wouldn't actually be needed, the system could interpret `.` and `..` anyway, but in the early days they were needed for the system to find the way back to the parent directory.

Comment: And to navigate Unix systems years before MS DOS...

Comment: @crashmstr: Yes, that is true. Subdirectories wasn't even part of the first version of DOS.

Comment: `.` and `..` pre-dates MS-DOS by many years and they are *still* needed for referencing relative directories.  Your answer is almost completely incorrect.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Are you sure that they are still actually needed? If the `..` entry in a directory becomes corrupted, is it impossible to get to the parent directory?

Comment: Yes of course they are still useful; for example if you have a directory called `bin` and a sibling directory `images` then you can you reference the `images` directory using `../images` from the `bin` directory.  How else could you reference a relative directory without additional configuration?  Your answer is almost complete fantasy.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Naturally, but are the directory entries still used to implement it? You are mixing up the function with the implementation.

Comment: Ah I understand what you are saying.  I don't know for sure, but I don't see why they wouldn't be used.  To check I'd have to go through the OSX kernel source code, and it wouldn't be trivial to find out in the time I'm willing to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

"." is a representation of the current directory in Unix based systems. ".." Is for upper directory.

Comment: It's also true of Windows-based file systems.  "Upper directory" is more correctly "parent directory".